# Redux Thunk / Eslint erro

Tags: redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm trying to build a React + Redux app, and I'm using Redux Thunk.

One of my action creators looks like this:

```js
import api from '../api';

export const FETCH_BOOKS = 'FETCH_BOOKS';

export default () => dispatch =>
  api
    .books()
    .perPage(-1)
    .then(books =>
      dispatch(books => ({
        type: FETCH_BOOKS,
        books,
      }))
    )
    .catch(error =>
      dispatch(e => ({
        type: 'ERROR',
        error: e,
      }))
    );
```

But when I run `yarn run build:production` I get the error(s):

```
ERROR in ./scripts/ll-app/actions/fetch-books.js

/Users/joneslloyd/resources/assets/scripts/ll-app/actions/fetch-books.js
   9:11  warning  'books' is defined but never used                                      no-unused-vars
  11:9   error    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  11:9   error    'books' is already declared in the upper scope                         no-shadow
  17:12  warning  'error' is defined but never used                                      no-unused-vars
  19:9   error    Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions
  19:9   error    'error' is already declared in the upper scope
```

However, I want to pass the `books` array (returned from the async api call) to the dispatch (anonymous function passed to dispatch) to then include said `books` array in the action, which the reducer will receive.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Even when I rename the inner reference to `books` it doesn't help.

It's possible I'm overlooking something in ES6 here.. But I basically want to take the `books` array returned from the api call (as a parameter of the `then` method), and then pass it into the `dispatch` function inside of that, as a parameter of the anonymous function I'm passing in.

Any help with this would be excellent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the source of the problem, but why do you need the inner ref to books at all? Your error msg/linter is complaining about that.

```js
...
  api
.books()
.perPage(-1)
.then(books =>
  dispatch({
    type: FETCH_BOOKS,
    books,
  })
).catch(error => dispatch({type: ERROR, error}))
```

why won't the above do what you want?

no function in the dispatch necessary here.

dispatch needs a plain action. A function in dispatch is giving you the error.
 When you see function in dispatch in the docs, those functions are function calls that are just returning the action.

```js
export someActionCreator = () => ({type: ACTION, payload})
dispatch(someActionCreator());
```

Your functions are just statements and are not returning the action to the dispatch. which would be more akin to something like

```js
export someActionCreator = () => ({type: ACTION, payload})
dispatch(someActionCreator);
```

see the difference?

Hope this helps!

Comment: You're totally right! Thanks a lot :)

Moving the inner ref to `books`/`error` solves it, but also your explanation makes total sense (I'm quite new to ES6).

Cheers